# Error handling for subtraction involving strings and numbers

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I some code which looks like this

```
 VariantArray3(i) = VariantArray2(j) - VariantArray1(k)
```

VariantArray2 and VariantArray1 are arrays created in VBA from rows in my spreadsheet.

They both contain a mixture of cells with only letters and cells with only numbers. I want to find a way to output N/A if either VariantArray2(j) or VariantArray1(k) is a string rather than a number. I've been told I can't use worksheet.function iferror for this, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you use `IsNumeric`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *might* work:

```
If IsNumeric(VariantArray2(j)) = True And IsNumeric(VariantArray1(k)) = True Then
    VariantArray3(i) = VariantArray2(j) - VariantArray1(k)
Else
    VariantArray3(i) = "N/A"
End If
```

Comment: This worked! I used the negative case IsNumeric(VariantArray2(j)) = False Or IsNumeric(VariantArray1(k)) = False.                      Thanks